# How to replace returned object with an error code?

Tags: prisma, apollo-server

I have a Apollo resolver that I use in combination with Prisma:

```js
export const userResolvers = {
  Mutation: {
    createUser: async (_, args) => {
      const sessionUsers = await prisma.session.findUnique({
        where: {
          id: Number(args.sessionId)
        },
        include: {
          players: true
        }
      })

      const userFound = sessionUsers.players.some((user) => user.name === args.name)

      if (userFound) {
        return 1004
      }

      return await prisma.user.create({
        data: {
          name: args.name,
          session: {
            connect: { id: Number(args.sessionId) },
          }
        }
      })
    },
  },
};
```

I want to check if a `user name` already exists in a certain session. If that's the case I want to return an error code, (just a number I suppose) like `1004`. Then in the front-end I can check for that code and show a notification to the user.

My check works, but the return value is empty user object:

[image]

Which makes sense since the return type for this resolver is a user object. Any suggestions how to add (or replace) the error code?

Comment: Normally you'd just throw a GraphQL error in your resolver and that would get back to the client. Otherwise createUser would have to return a UNION type between User and a number.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you return a status code *inside* the object (I would say always)?

Comment: Because the error code is not part of the user object.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with:

```js
try {
  if (sessionUsers.players.some((user) => user.name === args.name)) {
    throw 'Error'
  }

  return await prisma.user.create({
    data: {
      name: args.name,
      session: {
        connect: { id: Number(args.sessionId) },
      }
    }
  })
} catch (err) {
  throw new GraphQLError(
    'Username already taken', {
    extensions: {
      code: 1004,
    },
  });
}
```